# Laravel Flysystem SFTP: How to check if connection is successful or not

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-8, flysystem

I'm using Flysystem SFTP in Laravel 8. I've multiple accounts for sftp and I'm looping on every one for making adapter and then reading files from server. This all is working through console command and is registered in Schedule. The issue is when any of the connection fails due to username or password issue, it stops the execution of schedule task and skips the remaining. How can I check if connection is successful or not and continue to my next sftp connection. Thanks in advance.

```
foreach ($credentials as $cred) {
    try {
        $driver = Storage::createSFtpDriver($cred);
        if($driver->exists('/reports/')) {
          //Other code
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [SFTP V3](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/sftp-v3/), there `SftpConnectionProvider` reads:

> connectivity checker (must be an implementation of `League\Flysystem\PhpseclibV2\ConnectivityChecker` to check if a connection can be established (optional, omit if you don't need some special handling for setting reliable connections)

So the answer is `SftpConnectivityChecker implements` [`ConnectivityChecker`](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp/blob/3.x/ConnectivityChecker.php)
... to be passed into [`SftpConnectionProvider`](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp/blob/3.x/SftpConnectionProvider.php#L85) constructor. That `interface` only has one single method to override:

```
public class SftpConnectivityChecker implements ConnectivityChecker {
    public function isConnected(SFTP $connection): bool {
        $connected = false
        // TODO: inspect the $connection status.
        return $connected;
    }
}
```

Likely to be configured alike this:

```
'sftp' => [

    'connectivityChecker' => 'SftpConnectivityChecker'
]
```

---

And don't use `continue`, but handle the exception instead of ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm doing continue because I want to skip all accounts where connection is failed to establish.

Comment: But where to configue this? :) I'm not experienced developer. I'm just wondering how I can skip the failed connections and go to next one. I don't want it to stop execution on some exception.

Comment: See [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/diagnosis) for the exceptions it may throw... this is for the config, while the name-space in string `SftpConnectivityChecker` obviously needs to match. Just see the links provided; they show where/how. It's even completely unclear what `$cred` even is.

Comment: where can I override that configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is good way or not but in my case, it is working fine. I just solved it by applying `\` with Exception class and it is going fine.

```
foreach($credentials as $cred){
        try {
            $driver = Storage::createSFtpDriver($cred);
            if($driver->exists('/report/')){
              echo "Found for ".$cred["username"];
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: These are at least 3 different exceptions and you `continue` ignoring them; this is not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you using flysystem you need to catch Throwable.  All Flysystem exception implementation extends from Throwable.  I make the mistake of catching Exception and it just fall right through.

```
foreach($credentials as $cred){
    try {
        $driver = Storage::createSFtpDriver($cred);
        if($driver->exists('/report/')){
          echo "Found for ".$cred["username"];
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    catch (\Throwable $e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Another issue is if you have a long running process such as a queue worker that manage by supervisord then after the job run the worker never die so the connection never get disconnect properly.  There's a number of way you can solve this and depend on your needs:

Using Connectivity checker

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Core\MyConnectivityChecker;
use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;
use League\Flysystem\PhpseclibV3\ConnectivityChecker;

class MyConnectivityChecker implements ConnectivityChecker
{

    public function isConnected(SFTP $connection): bool
    {
        $connected = $connection->isConnected();
        if (!$connected) {
            // Ping will check if the connection if active or not.  If it's not active it will cleanly 
            // close the connection and reconnect again.
            $connection->ping();
        }

        return $connection->isConnected();
    }
}
```

The other option is disconnect the connection explicitly after every use:

```
foreach($credentials as $cred){
    try {
        $driver = Storage::createSFtpDriver($cred);
        if($driver->exists('/report/')){
          echo "Found for ".$cred["username"];
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }

        // force a disconnect
        $driver->getAdapter()->getProvideConnection()->disconnect();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```